# Processes and inodes

Tags: unix, filesystems, recovery, inode

I was trying to attempt a question on i-nodes and it got me little confused. Can anyone explain me the question please.

A System uses a log structured file system. A process issues a system call to create a file. The system crashes after allocating the i-node i but before allocating the data block b. what are the actions required to bring the file system to a consistent state?

Can anyone explain this question to me please.

Answer (score 1):

this sounds like an exam question?

i don't know what a "log structured" file system is, but the "log" implies you have a record of all the i-nodes.   in my experience, there are two groups, a free pool of unoccupied blocks and the occupied list.

occasionally, as a background task, scan the occupied list, looking for i-nodes with no associated block (implying something like 0 can't be a block #).   simply remove the i-node from the occupied list and return to the free pool.

Comment: Yeah Marty it was an exam question. I am getting ready to an exam and I was attempting previous paper questions.

Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: you're quite welcome.  that was the file system strategy for version 7 unix, at least, incl PWB Unix, System III.